# Unable to upgrade a Reporting Services project to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

We recently upgraded our Visual Studio 2015 to VS 2019. When I open one of our VS 2015 solution files in Visual Studio 2019 I'm not prompted to migrate and I receive the following error:

> Error Unsupported
>
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.  For more information
>   on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets,
>   please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after
>   clicking OK.
>
> - Financial Reporting, "Z:\Folders by Department\Finance\Reporting\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Financial
>     Reporting\Financial Reporting\Financial Reporting.rptproj"

How can I migrate this project?

Answer (score 26):

From my research it appears that as of Visual Studio 2017, `.rptproj` are not supported out of the box. You need to install the [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio&ssr=false) package in order to open this file type in Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2019:

> The [package contains the] Microsoft RDL report designer, projects and
>   wizards for creating professional reports. This package provides
>   support for the .rptproj type and is designed for the most recent
>   versions of Microsoft Reporting Services.

---

The RDLC Report Designer that came with previous versions of Visual Studio is also now a VSIX installation package - [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001&ssr=false).

Comment: Thank you installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio&ssr=false helping me a lot. After installation the project must be reloaded to be migrated in my case