# The version of Visual Studio is unable to open .rptproj

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I'm getting the error

```
The version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects.
....
"MyProject.rptproj"
```

I've seen this thread talking about the same error: [Unable to upgrade a Reporting Services project to Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362599/unable-to-upgrade-a-reporting-services-project-to-visual-studio-2019)
But the answer to it about installing  **Microsoft Reporting Services Projects** extension didn't solve my problem.
I have  **Microsoft Reporting Services Projects, SQL Server Integration Services Projects, Microsoft Analysis Services Projects and Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects** extensions installed and enabled. I tried disabling them, reopening VS, enabling them and reopening VS again, that didn't help. I also tried restarting my computer. Everything in SSRS is also configured properly. I also have SQL Server Data Tools installed in VS. Has anybody encountered this issue? Thanks in advance

Upd: Installing installing Visual Studio Extension Development in the VS installer didn't help, also My Visual Studio 2019 version is 16.11.11

Another note:
Even though I have Live Share disabled in VS Installer, I am still also getting Cascade Package warning:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project file and adding your reports to it?

Comment: @aduguid yeah, still the same problem :c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to download ["Microsoft Reporting Services Projects"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio&ssr=false) extension for my IDE "Visual Studio 2019" to fix that error and open my rptproj correctly.

Comment: For "Visual Studio 2022" it's the same extension required.

Comment: In my case, I had to run it twice because the 1st time it detected VS2017 & VS2019 but not VS2022, and then for the 2nd run, it detected VS2022.

Comment: I experienced problems when installing the extension from this link - it was saying that no compatible version of VS is found. However, I downloaded it a second time from inside Visual Studio - Extensions -> Manage Extensions. The file is with the same name but it seems a different version since there is 40 MB difference.